# Convert SQL query with 'WHERE IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM A)' TO 'JOIN'

Tags: sql

I want to ask, is it possible to transform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(B.id) FROM B
)
```

to SQL query with `JOINS` (without `WHERE IN` clause) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct way is:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT B.id
      FROM B
     ) B
     ON A.id = B.id;
```

This is often also used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.id = B.id;
```

However, this version removes duplicates from `A` (if any), whereas your original query does not.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do it, like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id=B.id
```

Comment: This will give multiple rows for all the values in B that are not unique